# Cron Jobs / Scheduled Tasks for Multi-Tenant with each tenant cron timings run parallely PHP app

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am having a scenario multi-tenants having their own settings.
Each tenants will have different timings like eg : 9:00 Am, 12:30pm,4:30pm to run cron to update the employee and job details from the third party API to single Mysql database with Yii2 according to the tenant settings.

I also tried to use with the help of AWS SQS but it wont run the cron parallely for each tenants
Checked with AWS Event bridge but its having only static way of solution.

For each tenants the job have to run parallely to updated their data.

Comment: Event Bridge schedule is a compelling option.  "its having only static way of solution" Create the schedules in accordance with the tenant settings.  Keep track of which event bridge schedule event belongs to each tenant.  That handles the scheduling.  Send the events to SQS and process the SQS queue in parallel.  "AWS SQS but it wont run the cron parallely for each tenants" that's a choice you can make at implementation of the SQS reader.  But for them to be processed in parallel, the clearly must also have the same schedule.

Comment: Another option is to use an API Destination for your Events and send them directly to your PHP API as an HTTP request.  Whatever runtime you're using for PHP, that will (assumedly) handle the requests concurrently.  That might be simpler than trying to parallelize in a language like PHP directly and doesn't require another invocation of your code besides the web.